# Can I modify a WP_Query instance or clone it with modifications?

Tags: wp-query

Let's say I have created a `all_movies` function that returns a `WP_Query` instance that includes all posts of a custom type `movie`.

```
$movies = all_movies(); // returns WP_Query instance
```

I would like to modify the `WP_Query` object to only show a certain author's movies, maybe in code like this:

```
$movies = all_movies();
$movies->filter(['author' => 14]); // not real code
```

Or maybe I could create a new `WP_Query` instance that copies the existing instance with modifications:

```
$movies = all_movies();
$new_movies = $movies->filter(['author' => 14]); // not real code
```

Of course, I would expect the query to be lazy only resolve at the last minute. I'm used to other ORM systems where something like this is possible. Is it possible with Wordpress' `WP_Query` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WP_Query` can repeatedly *loop* through the retrieved posts multiple times, but it was never meant to query them repeatedly/iteratively. You can just  do `$query->query($args)` again, but there is little point as opposed to just making a new clean object.

In your case I think it would make sens to have your custom function accept optional parameters, along the lines of:

```
function all_movies( $args = [] ) {

    $defaults_args = ['stuff'];

    return new WP_Query( array_merge( $default_args, $args ) );
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Just for completeness, is there a way to get args from an existing `WP_Query` object, so that I could do `new WP_Query($query->args)`?

Comment: That should be `$query->query_vars` on top of my head.